# Source for sample designs for a Tree House?

Tags: treehouse

I have a nice tree in my backyard, the base is easily 10+ feet in circumference.

I want to build my son a tree house.  More correctly I want to build a tree house with my son.

I was wondering if there is a good site with suggested plans.  I am not entirely sure how to tie into the tree trunk, in terms of the trees health and whatnot.

The first branch is 30+ feet up, so it would be just around a nice clean, cylindrical tree body.

Comment: How high do you plan to build it?  You might be better off building a raised deck type structure, with a large hole in the middle for the tree to pass through.  This way the tree is not damaged in any way, and you know the structure is safe since it will be supported by the footings and not the tree itself.

Comment: Also if you do a google image search for `tree house plans` you should get some good ideas.

Answer (score 2):

A good design would be what @Tester101 suggested.  Build a platform around the tree.  On one side of the platform could be the tree house.    Some examples are here:

http://www.buildeazy.com/plan_links_treehouses.html

There's a good picture of platform around a tree, now just imagine a bigger platform with a tree house on one side of it.